# Change a string inside style element via javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, element, edit

I have something like this:

```
<div id="page16" style="background-image: url(http://domain.domain/GetPageImg.ashx?Type=covered&gPageToken=71510eb3-e241-4c14-8dc7-46c4ee19f35b&nStep=7&nVersion=10&webp=true);"></div>
```

Anyway, This code basically gets an image that is covered. And I want to change the Type to page_img and reloading the pic to the updated one without reloading. How would I go around doing this?

Comment: you want to change background of image on which event?

Comment: and which code is that?

Comment: You have to have an event in order to change the image src...Although you don't need to reload the page

Answer (score 0):

jQuery code:

```
$("#page16").css("background-image","url ("+new_image_path+")");
```

Comment: I got multiple page16 divs (actually called pageX but doesn't matter), so I basically I need something to copy the current url and just change the Type.

Comment: you can use any selector that is not the problem. What do you mean change the type? it is a background URL, meaning an image which is used to draw the background of your element (div in this case), if you change the URL to a different one, than a different image will be displayed as background. See full documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var el = document.getElementById('page16');
var oldImg = el.style.backgroundImage;
el.style.backgroundImage = oldImg.replace('Type','page_img');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing you have a button and after click on this, the background image would be change. like

```
function changeImage(){
    var elem = document.getElmentById('page16').
    elem.style.backgroundImage = "url(here is your new image url)";
}

<input type="button" value="change background" onclick="changeImage()" />
```

You can call this function `changeImage()` on paticular event you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#page16').css('background-image', function(i,v){ return v.replace('covered', 'page_img'); });
```